# How to sing ending silent 'e'?

Tags: prononciation, musique

It is taught that ending 'e' or whole syllable is silent in speech.
But I've noticed that some singers kinda reserve a space for it (pause for a rhythm beat) and sometimes give it subtle or half realization.
Is it my illusion, the singers' specifics, or common practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's common practice. Sometimes even words that don't end with *e* have a long "eu" sound (mostly in children's songs)

See these examples:

[Nursery rhymes](https://youtu.be/Fo0pkcarE0U) with frequent and strong "eu" sounds at the end of verses.

["Adult" song](https://youtu.be/HDbpZpm9j9c) with "eu" sounds in the chorus. In this one the "eu" is sung in a different note than the rest of the word.

Answer (score -1):

The pronunciation of a final 'e' follows two rather simple rules:

- If the final 'e' is followed by a consonant other than a mute 'h', then it must be pronounced and counts as a syllable.
- If not, even at the end of a sentence or before some punctuation, then it is silent.

Comment: These rules apply in poetry (mostly), but songs often deviate from them.